# Send mail to initiator's manager in SAP Workflow

Tags: workflow, sap-basis

I'm trying to learn SAP workflow. I made some progress. But I need to do something like below.

I created a workflow that sends mail to initiator when a product order is created. What I want to do is to send mail to manager of initiator. So I need to learn to **bind the receiver** dynamically. I couldn't find any document for this purpose which is maybe because I don't know where to look.

Anyone can help about this ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to «**bind the receiver** dynamically» you have to write the function module, which will retrieve the manager of an initiator. The wanted info is stored in one of HR tree tables, you can ask some of SAP HR-module expert for the further details. The implemented function module you have to wrap with the ***public static*** method of ABAP class (otherwise you can't use this method in workflow template), and add the call of this method from the workflow template. Please, don't forget to set the binding in order to pass the ***_WF_INITIATOR*** value.